# What is the true origin of javax.faces.bean package?

Tags: java, maven, richfaces, mojarra

I'm just studying JSF, RichFaces and Maven. And I discovered strange thing:  `javax.faces.bean` package exits only in distribution available from http://javaserverfaces.java.net.

It doesn't exist in maven repository http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.1.4.
It looks that if I will try to build richfaces-4.0.0.Final\examples\richfaces-showcase it won't be retrieved either.

Currently I succeded only in using richfaces' calendar, because it doesn't use beans. But the problem is not about how to run all showcases successfully. The problem is how to make it in proper way, i.e. by retrieving the `javax.faces.bean` package through maven and through public maven repository.

I'm wondering isn't maven supposed to solve that kind of problems? And who responsible for the mess in this particular case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these classes and annotations are in the [jsf-api](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-api/2.1.5) jar.

Comment: I got it! The tutorial is too old. It references jsf-api 1.2, which doesn't contain the beans package. But richfaces-4.0.0.Final\examples\richfaces-showcase references 2.0 version, and it's ok. Thank you.